# Ember not doing network request to load links attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My app doesn't send any network request to get the **hasMany** through links of a particular Model.

These are my models:

```
var attr = DS.attr,
hasMany = DS.hasMany,
belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;

App.Agrupamento = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  escolas: hasMany('escola',{async:'true'})
});

App.Sessao = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  reservas: hasMany('reserva', {async:'true'})
});

App.Escola = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  agrupamento: belongsTo('agrupamento',{inverse:'escolas'}),
  reservas: hasMany('reserva',{async:'true'})
});

App.Reserva = DS.Model.extend({
  escola: belongsTo('escola'),
  sessao: belongsTo('sessao'),
  ...
});
```

The Agrupamento-Escola association does the request. 
As does the Escola-Reserva. But Sessao-Reserva does not trigger any network request when attempting to get the **hasMany** attribute.

I am using Ember's Inflector, could this be the cause?

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular("sessao","sessoes");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was other attribute's name, from model Sessao, probably a reserved name.